# how prevent horizontal scroll in bootstrap and list?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, horizontal-scrolling

I have a responsive UL List , many Li ImageItem and span are in this Ul. 
on maximize size 3 item shows in one row and when I resize ( small) my browser, 2 item shows  and it works fine. But in smallest size of my browser horizontal scroll appear :( 1 item shows but scroll appear, how I can prevent horizontal scroll?!
this is my css :

```
.myUl {
    font-size:large !important;
    color:#373636 !important;
    text-align:center !important;
}
.myUl li {
    width:350px !important;
}
.myUl li:hover {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) !important;
}
.myUl li img {
    height:170px !important;
    width:100px !important;
}
.myUl li span {
    float:right !important;
    width:170px;
    padding-right:8px !important;
    padding-top:10px !important;
    text-align:right !important;
    vertical-align:middle !important;
    line-height: 1.5em !important;
}
ul.img-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.img-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
}
ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

this is my Index.cshtml

```
<div>
    <ul class="img-list myUl">
        <li>
            <span>
                some text here
            </span>
            <span style="float: left !important; padding-top: 3px !important;">
                <a>
                    <img class="img-responsive img-circle img-thumbnail" src="~/Images/MenuImages/z.jpg"  />
                </a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
           .........
        </li>
  </ul>
```

an image of my page

Comment: Which element is causing the scrolling? Inspect the element and let me know :)

Comment: can you please share any jsfiddle or working demo where we can see issue in live? that will help..thanx

Comment: really I don't know which element causing this , I changes every thing but still scroll appear

Comment: thanks , I'm trying to show it in jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent horizontal scrolling just add this to your body tag in Css like such :

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Hope this helped

Comment: No problem glad I could help @shimaamini

Answer (score 0):

Your following code may leads to horizontal scrolling when screen width is going less than `360px`,

```
.myUl li {
  width:350px !important;
}
```

When the browser size goes below 350px your browser will shows a horizontal scrollbar If u need to overcome this issue you are required to write a media query for this, Like the following:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .myUl li {
      width:100% !important;
  }
}
```

also u can be use the property `body { overflow-x: hidden; }`

Comment: Thanks , myUL li is the reason , when I remove this css , Horizonatl scroll not appear . I insert you Media code but it doesn't work  and horizonatll scrool appear :/

Comment: ok then you are required to add an `body{overflow-x:hidden}`. This works fine.